# Passing state from child class to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that this is probably the most asked question about React, but none of the answers helped me.

I have 2 classes:

Child

```
class Preview extends Component {
constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.state = {
            isCommentOpen: false
        };
this.handleComment = ::this.handleComment;

render() {
return(
button type="button" onClick={this.handleComment}>Comment</button>
         )}
handleComment(){
        this.setState({isCommentOpen: !this.state.isCommentOpen});
               }        
export default Preview;
```

Parent

```
class Profile extends Component {
 render(){
        return(
        <div>
             <_.Preview />
//the place where I want to add validation from the component above
             {this.state.isCommentOpen ? <span>Cool</span> : null}
       </div>
}
```

Comment: You don't need to pass state from child to parent in (almost) any case. Put the state into the parent. [see docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: The answer that got selected as correct is mutating `this.props`, which is not really what is done usually in React. See my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should not mutate or directly assign `this.props` as shown in the other answer:**

```
this.props.isCommentOpen = !this.props.isCommentOpen // <-- DON'T DO THIS!
```

Instead, you should have a callback function to let the Parent component update the child component:

```
class Profile extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isCommentOpen: false;
    }
    this.handleComment = this.handleComment.bind(this); // <-- important!
  }

  handleComment() {
    this.setState({ isCommentOpen: !this.state.isCommentOpen });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Preview handleComment={this.handleComment} />
        { this.state.isCommentOpen ? <span>Cool</span> : null }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Profile
```

The child component then only needs to call `this.props.handleComment`:

```
// Child Component:
class Preview extends Component {

render() {
  return(
    <button type="button" onClick={this.props.handleComment}>Comment</button>
  }
}

export default Preview;
```